# Apache POI - word file to msxml

Tags: xslt, apache-poi, msxml

I have done a bunch of searching and have not found a simple answer to my question.

MS word allows you to Save As, and then select from a variety of formats. What I want to do is have POI open a word file, save as msxml (a truly hideous looking format) and then in a subsequent step, run an xslt transformation on the msxml file.

I saw posts for reading a word file, and then looping over all the text elements and build an xml doc from scratch that way, but I would prefer to do the xml transformation using xslt.

perl OLE allows you to do this. Is there a list of basic commands like that can be run from POI?

thanks.

Comment: "perl OLE allows you to do this. Is there a list of basic commands like that can be run from POI?" No! The aim of `apache poi` is reading and creating Microsoft Office files **whithout** the need of any Microsoft Office applications being installed. So no OLE Automation or Component Object Model is involved. So `apache poi` is only able reading the Microsoft Office file to get the data from it and then using that data for creating other formats (XML for ex.). It cannot interact with Microsoft Office applications.

Comment: that answers my question, thanks